# Why can't NVDA find the label name of date and number?

Tags: html, date, numbers, thymeleaf, nvda

I'd like to add label on my website using Thymeleaf fields, too.

I wrote the following code:

```
<form id="newFoo" action="#" th:action="@{'/save'}" th:object="${foo}"
            method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label for="name" form="newFoo">Name</label></td>
                    <td> 
                        <input id="name" type="text" th:field="*{name}" required="required">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label for="gender" form="newFoo">Gender</label> </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="gender" th:field="*{gender}" required="required">
                            <option th:each="g : ${genders}"
                                th:value="${g.id}" th:text="${g.name}" ></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label for="birthday" form="newFoo">Birthday</label></td>
                    <td> 
                        <input id="birthday" type="date" th:field="*{birthday}" min="1900-01-01" max="2100-01-01" required="required">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="height" form="newFoo">Height</label></td>
                    <td> <input id="height" type="number" th:field="*{height}" required="required"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

When I tried to navigate through my form by NVDA, only the labels of texts and select were shown and said. Numbers and date were not shown. I tried it on Google Chrome and on Firefox.

Trying [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/), number worked, too.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I copied your code exactly and ran in both chrome and firefox with nvda and I heard the labels for all four fields as I tabbed through the form.

Comment: As a copy, it worked well at me, too. However, when the Thymeleaf flieds got value, in the Inspector, they'll be shown as `value`. Trying with `value`, I got in the problem I described in the question above.